# Question about Inequalities (Strictness)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, analysis, inequality

If I have that $A(x) < B(x)$ for $x \in [-1,2]$, does it also hold that $A(x) \leq B(x)$? My intuition says yes just that the strict inequality makes more sense as $A$ will never equal $B$.

Comment: Yes, of course. The first statement implies the second.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you, I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: $\le$ is an "or" statement.   If is "either $A(x) < B(x)$ OR $A(x)=B(x)$".  Now if either condition is true then the whole statement is true.  If $A(x) < B(x)$ then it is true that either $A(x)<B(x)$ or $A(x)=B(x)$ is true because one of them *is* true.  And if $A(x)=B(x)$ then it is true that either $A(x) < B(x) $or $A(x)=B(x)$ is true because one of them *is* true.  [However $A(x) < B(x)$ is a stronger statment and says more than $A(x) \le B(x)$ does.  But  $A(x)< B(x) \implies (A(x)<B(x)$ OR $anything$.